# Multiple Author Voting System

Tags: collaboration, voting, vote

Is it possible to implement a voting system in a collaborative multiple author blog in which when a post is created, but before it is published, the authors on the site could vote yes or no on whether or not the content was on topic or relevant to the blog before the post goes public?

Does this exist already?

Answer (score 0):

Would certainly depend on the blogging software. In Drupal, the Workflow plugin (http://drupal.org/project/workflow) is pretty much the go-to module for that sort of thing - although Drupal is more of a CMS than a blog (although you could use it as a blog). With Wordpress, Approval Workflow (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/approval-workflow/) seems to be the simpler way to go.